# How to generate static HTML pages from ASP.NET Web Forms app

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a Web Forms app solution made with Visual Studio 2013 and I want to generate static `HTML` pages from it. Does anyone know a good tool or maybe script and had experience with this?

I tried with `Pretzel`, but it does not support ASP.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're looking to generate a static pages from the ASP.NET pages? Just making sure there isn't a better solution.

Comment: @Kirk "You need to find some tool or VS plugin or IIS plugin or similar that can easily do this. The plan is that all those Default.aspx and other .aspx pages will be generated as static html. Default.aspx -> Default.html, Page1.aspx -> Page1.html etc... The result after the tool is run should be a list of ordinary html pages, without any need of any background cs code.
" My task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used and it is working fine:

```
Uri url = new Uri(serverPath + pageName);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept,"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0");

string finalHTML = wc.DownloadString(url);

//change the asp extensions if there are any linking
finalHTML = finalHTML.Replace(".aspx", ".html");    

//create HTML file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(string.Format("{0}{1}", filePathSave, pageName), finalHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate HTML pages using `HtmlTextWriter`  as:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("fileName.html")))
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);

    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);
    writer.Write("Head Contents");
    writer.RenderEndTag();

    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);
    writer.Write("Body Contents");
    writer.RenderEndTag();

    writer.RenderEndTag();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had problems with rendering.